# How to make TabHost fullscreen (Android 2.3)

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fullscreen

Can the `TabHost` in Android 2.3 be **fullscreen**? 
Usually, I use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in an activity prior to setting the content view, but for some reason, doesn't seem to work for the `TabHost`.

What am I missing?

Comment: you can set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: If this doesn't work means, you can simply try to give the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitlebar.FullScreen` to your `activity` tag in your manifest file..

Comment: that's nice and even smarter for all activities. if someone makes that an answer, I'll gladly accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. You should do like this.

```
public class ActivityName extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Make sure. You'd given the `requestWindowFeature` method and setting the `flag` before calling `setContentView` Hope this will helps you. Its work fine for me.

or you can do this in `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: I have done as mentioned here. But it doesnot work for me. It works fine for all other android versions but not 2.3. Is there any special fix available for android version 2.3